# set admin/user permission to see any web page

Tags: html, web-applications, web

I am working on web application. As an admin you can see one particular button, which opens a page.

As a user you cannot see that button. But, if you type the url of that page, it opens.

I want that page to be opened by admin only. How do I proceed?

Comment: Please post the code or any information about your work on this till now.

Comment: thanks.
for my code , this worked : 
if(req.session.role == 'admin'){ res.render( //page name.ejs ) }

Answer (score 2):

In your web.config file add this to allow and deny user.

```
   <authorization>
   <allow users="*"/>  or <deny user="?"/>      
   </authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page is called, There would be some session available for the user / admin who logged in on the site ?

Check the session value as who logged in based on that show the button

```
eg :
suppose $_SESSION['user_type'] =  "admin" // admin id 
if($_SESSION['user_type'] == "admin"){
//show button
}
```

Comment: thanks for my code , this worked :

if(req.session.role == 'admin'){
res.render( //page name.ejs )
}